# Change the part of increment formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using below formula in google sheets, i wanted it to just change the second letter after & operator. i.e l72, m72, m72. But there is no effect on it. I tried putting a dollar in front of number but still it doesn't work.

```
((indirect($H2&"!L72")-indirect($H2&"!L88"))/(indirect($H2&"!L72")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can you try:*

```js
=let(x,L72, y,L88, z,indirect($H2&"!"&address(row(x),column(x))),
     (z-indirect($H2&"!"&address(row(y),column(y))))/z)
```

Comment: Hi it worked beautifully, can you please share what you did here. I am new to this.

Comment: I am attributing *Cell_L72* to `x` using let function→  I need the cell address for indirect function, so `address(row(x),column(x))` = `address(row(L72),column(L72))` which outputs $L$72

Comment: what is the use of z here.

Comment: Just like how I assigned L72 to `x` via let function; this formula `indirect($H2&"!"&address(row(x),column(x)))` is assigned to `z` so that in the later stages I can just use the variable `z` instead of repeating that formula part again n' again...

Comment: Its kinda tough to create formulas *if no test data is provided & a plain formula is shared with limited to no context.* For future `1` You can easily share the sample sheet data via this [table generator](https://markdown-convert.com/en/tool/table). Just paste the *data rows/columns* in this generator→press enter→then copy-paste the data here in the question as a table→super simple. `2` you can also share a test sheet using this [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) & is super recommended